# youtube iframe api not pausing video

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-api, slider, youtube-iframe-api

I am currently working on a page with a slider with various iframe youtube embeds.

I am trying to get my JS to pause the video when you hit the "next" button on the slider. I think I've got everything set up according to the api.. but it doesn't seem to pause the videos when you click the slider button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

// global variable for the player
var player;

// this function gets called when API is ready to use

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

  // bind events

  var pauseButtonRight = document.getElementByID("pause-right");
  pauseButtonRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });
   var pauseButtonLeft = document.getElementByID("pause-left");
  pauseButtonLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });
}

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
</script>
```

my iframes:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6QB6jVjA2js?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things :

- this is `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID`
- you've instanciated a Youtube player with id `'video'` but your iframe don't have any id :

  ```
  <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6QB6jVjA2js?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>
  ```
- use `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` instead of `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`

You will have something like :

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var pauseButtonRight = document.getElementById("pause");
  pauseButtonRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });
  var pauseButtonLeft = document.getElementById("play");
  pauseButtonLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });
}

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

with :

```
<iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6QB6jVjA2js?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>
<input id="pause" type="submit" value="pause" />
<input id="play" type="submit" value="play" />
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/5mtj9Lbe/)

Check [Youtube iframe API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: Thank you for your help on this... this worked great.

Comment: just one thing tho, you don't need the event attribute on onPlayerReady function, It's not being used anyway.